# Angular 1+2 hybrid app dev: ts transpiled on browser with systemjs0.20 + plugintypescript

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, browser, systemjs

I tried to load angulajs from systemjs.config.js, not from index.html, but it failed, the application can't find 'angular'.

- With a script to load AngularJS in index.html, it's working:
  plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wqB0sNXI6QeWjpl5MJWr

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/angular@1.6.6/angular.js"></script>`
- With instructions in systemjs.config.js, it isn't:
  plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qcgI938K75dwuI8x0PUY

  `map: {
      app: 'src',
      // angularjs
      'angular': 'npm:angular@1.6.6', 
      [...]
   },
  packages: {
      [...]
      'angular': {
          main: 'angular.js',
          format: 'global',
          defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },`

Is it possible? Then what am i missing?

Comment: just curious, why do you want to use angular 1 and 2?

Comment: @Ero I guess he need to migrate existed project from the 1

Comment: @Lyubinov is right. The idea is to start a new version with Angular 4 but we have legacy code whose part of it uses ui-grid.